# Docker Linux - Limit global resources

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, docker, gitlab

I am using docker with gitlab-runner on linux (Ubuntu 16.04).
gitlab-runner starts up to 4 concurrent docker containers.

I have an 8-core CPU, and I would like to limit the global usage to 4 cores. The only way I found is to limit the number of cores run for each docker container to 1. However, this solution is not the best since if only 2 containers are run, only 2 cores will be used instead of allowing 2 cores for each.

Is there any way to limit the global number of CPUs used for docker (as it is possible with Mac and Windows through the desktop app) in linux?